# What is the reason for Hive Exception CloseOperation Failed : out of sequence response

Tags: exception, jdbc, hive

I've a java application in which with Hive JDBC connection, I'm trying to run hive queries with multiple threads that means we have multiple queries running in parallel. It was working fine before few days but not  it's failing in Prod. I would like to know what went wrong. I'm using cloudera CDH my hive jdbc driver ver is <1.1.0-cdh5.7.1>.

Can someone please tell me more about Hive Exception **CloseOperation Failed: out of sequence response**